# Structure of a Java Web Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have developed various Java EE web-applications in `Netbeans` by selecting `webapplication` as the project type.

Now, I want to start coding a web-application in `Eclipse`. The application will be based on `Struts` framework.

The structure of the project created by `Netbeans` and `Eclipse` are different.

Q1. What project type I should choose for the above application in `Eclipse`? I chose `DynamicWebApplication` as the project type.

Q2. Which project structure to use for the web-application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project structures are arbitrary - as chosen by the IDE developers.

DynamicWebApplication is a fine choice for web-app.

Leave it to the IDE to form your structure and subsequently automate the build process.

However, I'd suggest another option for structure & build process - [Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/) - it imposes a different structure, but provides easy dependency and build management.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose DynamicWebApplication as your project type